# Customising UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar.

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, customization

I have a separate customisation class that does all the customisation of controls.
I am also customising navigation bar buttons.

Now in navigation VC's viewDidLoad, I am passing a reference to the VC's leftBarButtonItem, to the customisation class, and the reference is of type UIBarButtonItem. But how will he customisation class know, that the passed reference to the UIBarButtonItem is the left button?
I need the class to know this, since the customisation for left button is different from the right button.
I want to avoid creating a custom Enum for that, if it's possible to do it with built-in framework capabilities.

Can you help please?

Comment: piece of code would be helpful.

Comment: you may use tags.. u can have leftBtn.tag = 0; & rightBtn.tag = 1;
In customization class depending on tag u can come to which barBtn is it..

Comment: I am legally binded not to post concrete code unfortunately. But it is a question about cocoa touch framework capabilities and for some technique to detect a trait/property. The description is just giving context for it. Ask for specifics please if I didn't describe the problem clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while back. You will probably want to make your customization method have an argument that tells it what kind of button you are passing

```
[CustomizationClass customizeButton:leftBarButton ofType:kLeftBarButton];
```

Then make the customizeButton method check for the "ofType" and customize accordingly.

EDIT: just read what you said about custom enums. As far as I know, there is no way to detect this.

Comment: I came up with an idea. The leftBarButtonItem property of UINavigationItem is always pointing to the first item in the leftBarButtonItems array. So theoretically I could pass the reference to the navigationItem to the customization class along with the left/rightButtonBarItem and in the customization class check, to which of the two arrays (array for left items or array for right items) it belongs. This way I will know what side I am dealing with.